# Changing execution time of program

Tags: c#, list, time, stopwatch

I have a program that takes a text file, read each line and then insert each line to a list. 
I used `stopwatch` to calculate time of execution. But there is some droll result! I'll give various elapsed time when I run the program each time (difference is about 1 or 2 seconds).

The text file involves 3 million URLs.

Any idea??!

Comment: So you are sending three MILLION requests over the network each time and wonder about a few seconds difference between the various runs? That's because retrieving something from the network takes some time, and that time depends on various factors, many of which you cannot control and may change all the time.

Comment: Any answer without looking at your code is probably going to be wrong. Moreover you are almost using wrong technology here given your question. Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fluctuation is perfectly normal, especially when the code involves IO such as reading files.

Comment: Why? Is there a good reason for it and is there any way that I can solve this problem??

Comment: How is it a problem? Do you somehow depend on constant execution time?

Comment: Yes I want constant execution time for my program and this is so important because every seconds is important for me.

Comment: Sure, sure. But "fast" and "constant" are very different things. And no matter how fast your application runs, it will **never** run with constant execution time. Not on an ordinary PC where your application shares the operating system, memory, CPU(s), HDD etc. with dozens of other applications, processes, threads etc.

Comment: Well Sebastian, I got your points and I think I should run my program multiple times and calculate the average time... But do you have any idea about how I can improve reading from file? (e.g. I tried insert it to a list and then read from it, but the memory usage will increase)

Answer (score 4):

The processing time for a set of commands depends on (but is not limited to):

- the CPU speed
- the efficency of your code
- asyn vs sync methods
- network speed
- the networked computer
- hard drive speed
- ram
- my mood
- ...

I could go on for days here. The point is (as TheifMaster said), there are so many variables at stake here that it would be a miracle if your code had the same time for any 2 runs! It's the "every snowflake is different" methodology. With so many environment variables, no 2 runs will be the same.

Don't fret on time differences, just focus on getting the average time as low as you need to.

Comment: Well, maybe not "as low as you can", but "as low as you need to".

Comment: @JohnSaunders, agreed. Forgot that premature optimization is one of the programming evils.